# Overlay Image with New Color

Tags: javascript, css, html

So here is my issue:

I have a two-tone png image. One tone is black, one tone is transparent.

I am currently using the background color attribute to change the color of the transparent section dynamically.

I would also like to be able to change the black section dynamically using a mask overlay. I assume this is possible in html5 canvas, and possibly css, but I have been unable to find a working answer.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, webkit (and only webkit) can do it with pure CSS. It's [really, really, really not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask).

A couple links to get you started, should you be interested:

- http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/
- http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/

Comment: Although these technically do-not solve my problem, I believe it is as close to a solution as possible. Also, masking text as in the second link is *totally awesome*.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood you correctly.

You can use the html5 element canvas to manipulate images right down to individual pixels.

Try this site for reference:

http://beej.us/blog/2010/02/html5s-canvas-part-ii-pixel-manipulation/

Comment: Hi Decad, thank you for your answer. I am aware of this ability, I was wondering if there was already pre-defined functions for masking an image?

Answer (score 0):

Well, canvas is supported by most modern browsers, if you can take jquery as a solution. You can try this jquery plugin.

the command is pretty straightforward and as easy as:

```
$("#myImageID").tancolor();
```

There's an interactive [demo](http://nicolaisi.github.io/tancolor/). You can play around with it.

Check out the documentation on the usage, it is pretty simple. [docs](https://github.com/nicolaisi/tancolor)